# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, iis, windows-server

para una plataforma web que reporta el siguiente error 
[image: error403]
 que opciones de solución se tiene?, es en IIS y el sitio junto con las carpetas de proyecto tienen ya los permisos de al administrador y del usuario IIS, incluso en la appPool.
Esto es en un servidor de hostgator recien liberado.

Las carpetas de mi plataforma estan en wwwroot, ahí en las propiedades tienen permiso total los usuarios de IIS, y el administrador que me proporcionaron. En IIS la appPool que apunta a mi plataforma tiene las credenciales del administrador, y cuando me logueo o incluso antes de loguearme si recargo muchas veces la pagina aparece ese error, desde internet con el dominio que le dí o de forma local, en ambos casos sucede lo mismo

Es una plataforma web MVC, esta conectada a MongoDB
Act. En los eventos de las aplicaciones esto es lo que me sale, podría estar relacionado? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias de antemano por sus comentarios.

Comment: y a que direccion estas queriendo acceder? no sirve de mucho que pases una foto del error si no adjuntas mas informacion.

Comment: Parece que estuvieras publicando mal los archivos en la carpeta Principal de forma equivocada o algo asi

Comment: Gracias por responder, te comento las carpetas de mi plataforma estan en wwwroot, ahí en las propiedades tienen permiso total los usuarios de IIS, y el administrador que me proporcionaron. En IIS la appPool que apunta a mi plataforma tiene las credenciales del administrador, y cuando me logueo o incluso antes de loguearme si recargo muchas veces la pagina aparece ese error, desde internet con el dominio que le dí o de forma local, en ambos casos sucede lo mismo.

Comment: Angel. No has proporcionado suficiente información. Qué tipo de aplicación es? Un servicio WCF? Una página ASPX? WebApi2? MVC?

Comment: @Arriel gracias por responder, acabo de actualizar con la duda que me compartes y pues es una plataforma web MVC

Comment: Hago eco de la pregunta de @Ramiro. Cuál es la URL?

Comment: Hola @Arriel Lo intento desde un subdominio, el cual es demo.assetsapp.com, pueden cargarlo en sus navegadores y actualizar varias veces, tambien lo tengo de forma local en el puerto 81, donde también se presenta el mismo error. Gracias de antemano por sus comentarios.